# Track a development application on twitter?

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I have a twitter account. Also signed in and created two applications in the development environment on twitter

```
https://apps.twitter.com
```

Using `Tweetsharp`, I am able to read the tweets and post tweets in C# using the keys. I can see the tweets on my twitter account.

I am confused by one thing: When I go to my twitter account, while I can see the tweets, I can't tell that it was created by a particular application. Is there a way to track tweets sent from a particular application credentials, and also, to create a channel so that people can see tweets from one or the other independently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter API still exposes how a tweet was created in the `source` property of a tweet response. It’s just that most of the clients today no longer display it (since a large fraction is coming through Twitter’s own apps now, making it less relevant for normal users). So you can still see it there.

There is however no way to get metrics about it currently. The only thing you could do is listen to the public stream and check the apps there. But that’s of course not a reasonable solution, so that leaves you just with having to add metrics into your app, or just ignoring it (that’s probabyl the better idea).

Finally, to answer the question in the title: The purpose of the apps is simply to manage authorization access. Users using your app need to authorize it to use Twitter on their behalf. So it’s a way to gain authorization while leaving them the power to shut you down at any time (they maintain the control, and can decide to terminate your access on a per-app basis).

Comment: I discovered a possible way to structure apps: https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169620?lang=en